# Как спарсить информацию на сайте python?

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите, как взять информацию по конкретной ссылке из закрытой вкладки. Переходя на страницу, чтобы посмотреть другие данные, необходимо нажать на кнопку и тогда открывается дополнительная карточка.
Достаю массивы ссылок:

```
for i in range(10):
url = f"https:example.com={i}"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('div', {'data-qaid': 'company_link'})
for titles in titles:
    title = titles.find('span', {'data-qaid': 'company_link'})
    link = titles.find('a')['href']
    if(my_links.__contains__(f'{title} {link}')):
        pass
    else:
        my_links.append(f'{title} {link}')
```

for item in my_links:
print(item)

Comment: "необходимо нажать на кнопку" используйте сеоенимум, чтоб нажать на кнопку в браузере.

Comment: можно пример пожалуйста

Comment: https://yandex.kz/search/?text=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC%2C+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B2+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD&lr=10298

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать